# SQL request LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, request, left-join

Let's say I have these table:
What should be my sql request to get the expected result?

table user_group:

```
group_id          |   user_id       |   is_active
1                          2               1
1                          3               1
2                          2               1
4                          2               1
```

table group :

```
id |     name
1       group1
2       group2
3       group3
4       group4
5       group5
6       group5
```

expected result

```
group_id       |      name      | user_id    |   is_active
 1                   group1         2               1
 2                   group2         2               1
 3                   group3         2               0
 4                   group4         2               1
 5                   group5         2               0
 6                   group6         2               0
```

I tried

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, ug.user_id, ug.is_active
FROM group g
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group uc ON ug.group_id = g.id
WHERE ug.user_id =2
```

but I only have the groups where user 2 is IN (so group1, group2 and group4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  id ,
        name ,
        COALESCE(user_ID, 2) user_id ,
        COALESCE(is_active, 0) is_active
FROM    tableGroup
        LEFT JOIN user_group ON id = group_id
                                AND user_Id = 2
```

You can fiddle with this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94eb8/8/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, ug.user_id, ug.is_active 
FROM group g 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group uc ON ug.group_id = g.id AND ug.user_id =2
```

When you have the condition in the where clause, you turn the left join into an inner join.

Comment: @Mathieu - This puts in NULLs into groups 3, 5 and 6 due to the LEFT JOIN. Hence does not match your expected output. What am I missing? Check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94eb8/7/0). Did you mistate the question requiring them to be NULLs instead of 2-0?

Comment: @Kash appears to be right, I did not notice that part.  If you agree, please unselect me as the correct answer and check his answer.

Comment: yes I figured out how to finish the job by myself with the coalesce. Thank you Kash I checked you as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_group.*, user_group.user_id, IFNULL(user_group.is_active, 0)
FROM table_group
LEFT JOIN user_group ON table_group.id = user_group.group_id
```